# Weird PHP substr() issue

Tags: php, substr

I've got a feeling this is a silly/stupid mistake on my part, but I need a new set of eyes... I'm trying to loop through a string using substr but am not getting what's expected.

For example, `echo substr("950122", 2, 2);` outputs 01 to the screen instead of 5. And using an index of 3 gives me 122 instead of 0.

How would I loop through the string correctly?
http://ideone.com/YKz7g3

```
<?php
$str = "950122";
for( $i = 1; $i <= strlen( $str ); $i++ ) {
    echo substr( $str, $i, $i ) . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why is this weird? Did you read [the manual](http://us3.php.net/substr)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The start position begins at `0` not `1`. So to get `5` you use `1,1` and to get `0` use `2,1`.

`0,1` will give you the first character `9`.

Also, the third parameter to `substr()` is the length, so if you use `1` you get 1 character from the `start` or `2` gives you 2 characters from the start.

`0,6` will give `950122`.

Comment: Yup, the 3rd param was my bad... I've been scripting in Lua and its 3rd param is the position of the last char you want. I knew it was something silly. :) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1) `i` should be 0

2) it should be `substr( $str, $i, 1 )` not `substr( $str, $i, $i )`

Comment: you actually want `( $str, $i, 1 )` don't you? 3rd param is length, not end point

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/9qlwje

```
<?php
$str = "970122";
for( $i = 0; $i <= strlen( $str ); $i++ ) {
    echo substr( $str, $i, 1 ) . "\n";
}
?>
```